# cambiar color del burguer menu dependiendo del background de la seccion

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

estoy haciendo un menu de hambuerguesa como un componente y fijo o sea con la propiedad fixed, este tiene las tres lineas de la caracteristica del menu estas son blanas lo que necesito es que cuando este en una seccion que es blanca esta cambie a negro, aun ocupe el [Methods for Contrasting Text Against Backgrounds](https://css-tricks.com/methods-contrasting-text-backgrounds/)
pero no funciono ya que para que funcione el bg debe estar en el div padre del componente y no donde lo mando a llamar, entonces si alguien me pudiera ayudar a como realizar para que cambie de color o si hay ya algun npm de un hamburguesa que cambie de color respecto al bg

este seria mi codigo sobre el menu ocupor `nextjs` con `typescript`

```
import { StyledHamburger } from "./Hamburger.styled";

export type Props = {
  open: boolean;
  setOpen: (v: boolean) => void;
};

const Hamburger = (props: Props) => (
  <StyledHamburger open={props.open} onClick={() => props.setOpen(!props.open)}>
    <div />
    <div />
    <div />
  </StyledHamburger>
);

export default Hamburger;
```

styles:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

import { colors } from "../global";

export const StyledHamburger = styled.button<{ open: boolean }>`
  position: fixed;

  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;

  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 2;

  div {
    position: relative;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 0.25rem;
    border-radius: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transform-origin: 1px;
    background-color: ${({ open }) =>
      open ? colors.pearl : colors.pearl};

    :first-child {
      transform: ${({ open }) => (open ? "rotate(45deg)" : "rotate(0)")};
    }

    :nth-child(2) {
      opacity: ${({ open }) => (open ? "0" : "1")};
      transform: ${({ open }) => (open ? "translateX(20px)" : "translateX(0)")};
    }

    :nth-child(3) {
     
      transform: ${({ open }) => (open ? "rotate(-45deg)" : "rotate(0)")};
    }
  }
  p {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transform-origin: 1px;
    background-color: ${({ open }) =>
      open ? colors.pearl : colors.pearl};
      transform: ${({ open }) => (open ? "translateX(20px)" : "translateX(0)")};
  }
`;
```

Comment: ¿Lo que necesitas es que cuando el usuario este encima de alguno de esos 3 div, cambien su color a negro? Saludos

Comment: no, el menu hamburguesa esta fijo cuando hago scroll y este pasa por una seccion que es blanca que el menu cambie a negro